# gitlab npm registry failing

Tags: npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci, npm-publish

I'm trying to publish a test for a npm package but it constantly fails.
In my package.json I have named the package after "@username/package_name" and also configured the publishConfig object:

```
"publishConfig": {
    "@username:registry": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<projectID>/packages/npm"
  },
```

My CICD YAML file is configured this way:

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - publish

publish:
  stage: publish

  before_script:
    - echo "@username:registry=http://${CI_SERVER_HOST}:${CI_SERVER_PORT}/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/">.npmrc
    - echo "//${CI_SERVER_HOST}:${CI_SERVER_PORT}/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}">>.npmrc

  script:
    - npm publish
```

and it fails with

```
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<projectID>/packages/npm
```

Any thoughts on what's wrong?

I've read a lot, tried to downgrade node version to 20, 18 and even 16. I followed tutorials and Gitlab documentation. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Which user is running the pipeline ?
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html#gitlab-cicd-job-token-security
CI_JOB_TOKEN specfies:

The token has the same permissions to access the API as the user that caused the job to run.

Comment: The user running pipeline is the project owner. According to documentation it shoud be enough to publish package.
Furthermore I'm using exactly the same CICD file listed as project doc: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/index.html#publishing-a-package-by-using-a-cicd-pipeline
Still having back 
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXXX/packages/npm

Comment: On top of that I tried to tackle down the problem to smaller pieces. So I generated a personal token with read and write permissions to the registry and created this local .npmrc (replacing the parameters of course):
@scope:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECTID>/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECTID>/packages/npm/:_authToken=<TOKEN>
When I run npm publish it fails almost immediately. Seems it never even called the endpoint given how fast it fails.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [in the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/#publishing-a-package-by-using-a-cicd-pipeline) don't specify `CI_SERVER_PORT` if it's a default port:

> When generating the `.npmrc` file, do not specify the port after `${CI_SERVER_HOST}` if it is a default port, such as `80` for a URL starting with `http` or `443` for a URL starting with `https`.

So, you should use something like this:

```yaml
  script:
    - echo "@username:registry=https://${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/" > .npmrc
    - echo "//${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" >> .npmrc
    - npm publish
```

Comment: You're right. But nevertheless the publish fails with the same error after I tweaked my YAML file. Here's the new one:

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - publish

publish:
  stage: publish

  script:
    - echo "@username:registry=https://${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/" > .npmrc
    - echo "//${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" >> .npmrc
    - npm publish
```